# Reference to a cell in an other table in a Word document from a field

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

How to reference to a cell in an other table from a field? I.e. I mean the following:

I have 2 tables in a Word document and I have to make a reference to any cell (e.g. `R1C1`) of the first from the any cell (e.g. `R1C1`) of the second. I have to do this using fields. So how can I perform such thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Highlight the table and insert a bookmark called Table. Move to your other table and insert a field, then simply reference the other table using the bookmark e.g:

```
{ =SUM(Table A1:A5) }
```

Answer (score 5):

Small extra info: this only works inside a formula. `=Tbl1 C2`
does not work; if you need the value of a single cell, use e.g.
`=AVERAGE(Tbl1 C2)`.

On the current Mac office (16.16, German locale), there is a bug that when you edit the formula later, the space character is missing, so in the dialog it says `=AVERAGE(Tbl1C2)`. You need to add the space character back in, or there is a syntax error.