# How to make cell "mirror" the value of a cell in another table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010 to create an invoice, and I know formulae can be used to compute the values of cells within a single table. However, I have two tables in my document, and need a formula that will take the value of **Cell Y** in the second table (a total calculated from all the above cells in that table) and "mirror" it to Cell X of the first table (a more prominent, nicely-formatted total):

[image]

This is the simplest/crudest way I can think of to accomplish this, but to have Cell X actually compute its value using the same cells that just like Cell Y does would be a much more superior solution - it just doesn't seem to me that Word's formulae capabilities are up for it.

Is it possible to do what I want with Word? The key to this seems like it would be figuring out how to use a Word table formula to reference a table outside of itself, if that's possible, but I haven't yet found anything on how to do that.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/571051/reference-to-a-cell-in-an-other-table-in-a-word-document-from-a-field

Comment: Didn't manage to find that in my search, thank you.