# How to refer to a cell from word table outside of table?

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

`{ IF { COMPARE wow A2 > 10 } = 1 "working" "not" }`

Here "wow" is bookmark to the table.
Value of cell is 8 so if field should return "not" but returning "working" not matter what I change it this comparison is returning 1.
How this is hapening ?.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best method would be to establish individual bookmarks for the relevant table cells rather than rely or relative addressing.

In other words bookmark the cell "wow_A1" and use that for your comparison.

Comment: By far I know we have to rely on functions like =sum() etc to refer to a cell in word table

Comment: Can you give a specific example? Outside of tables, you can use calculation fields. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-formula-field-32d5c9de-3516-4ec3-80ed-d1fc2b5bc21d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/571051/reference-to-a-cell-in-an-other-table-in-a-word-document-from-a-field, in particular note re using AVERAGE function to return value of a cell in a bookmarked table